# WPF - Radial menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I recently created an HTML page where I used this menu (see Figure). I need to create something similar in WPF. Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this. Thank you.
[Codepen menu](http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/LELBEo)`-`
[Radial menu preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFePV.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Infragistics has a [Radial Menu control](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/menus/radial-menu), but it's not free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of examples out there.

[This](https://alexpkent.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/wpf-radial-context-menu-pie-menu/) is probably one of the better ones.

Basically the way to start is to create a panel that is laid out radially - i.e. in a circle.  Most examples start by inheriting from the Panel class.  Then overridding the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods.  A fairly simple example of this is the code below. We are assuming a fixed item size (ItemHeight, and ItemWidth). There is a field 'UseFerrisWheelLayout' that allows you to control whether the items will be straight or transformed based on its position in the circle.

```
public class RadialPanel : Panel
{
  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  {
    if (constraint.Width == double.PositiveInfinity || constraint.Height == double.PositiveInfinity)
        return Size.Empty;

    foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
    {
        child.Measure(new Size(ItemWidth, ItemHeight));
    }
    return constraint;
  }

  protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
  {
    // Calculate radius
    double radiusX = (finalSize.Width - ItemWidth) * 0.5;
    double radiusY = (finalSize.Height - ItemHeight) * 0.5;

    double count = InternalChildren.Count;

    // Sector angle between items
    double deltaAngle = 2 * Math.PI / count;

    // Center of the ellipse
    Point center = new Point(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height / 2);


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        UIElement child = InternalChildren[i];

        // Calculate position
        double angle = i * deltaAngle;
        double x = center.X + radiusX * Math.Cos(angle) - ItemWidth / 2;
        double y = center.Y + radiusY * Math.Sin(angle) - ItemHeight / 2;

        if (UseFerrisWheelLayout)
        {
            child.RenderTransform = null;
        }
        else
        {
            child.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            child.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        }

        child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, ItemWidth, ItemHeight));
    }
    return finalSize;
  }
}
```

This is probably the best place to start, and then you can start customizing to your needs.